# embeding flash object while retrieving it from database

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-designer

[SharePoint Designer 2007] I am creating a master detail form that on using a master item, according flash movie loads and displayed. I am using the following code to embed a flash object (which is generated by adobe captivate):

```
<div id="CaptivateContent">&nbsp;</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       var so = new SWFObject("Sample.swf", "Captivate", "1361", "800", "9", "#CCCCCC");
        so.addParam("quality", "high");
        so.addParam("name", "Captivate");
        so.addParam("id", "Captivate");
        so.addParam("wmode", "window");
        so.addParam("bgcolor","#f5f4f1");
        so.addParam("menu", "false");
        so.addVariable("variable1", "value1");
        so.setAttribute("redirectUrl", "http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash");
        so.write("CaptivateContent");
    </script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('Captivate').focus();
        document.Captivate.focus();
    </script>
```

How can I make it get the SWFObject parameter from database? Am I on the right path?

Comment: What database? You shouldn't connect to the SharePoint one directly. Is this a third party database?

Comment: It is a SharePoint list, but I have problem with how to pass the parameter to the SWFObject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, what do you mean when you say Database, is it stored in a document library? If so you may want to use something like the DataViewWebPart with custom XSLT to insert the FileLeaf ref into the `new SWFObject` declaration.

If it is in a physical database, then you will need some code (or a BDC connection) to grab the location, or pull the blob to the accessible web file system, and then push this reference into the `new SWFObject` declaration.

Comment: I have problem with the part "push this reference into the new SWFObject declaration". Is this possible using SharePoint Designer?

Comment: If using a BDC connection you can use DataViewWebPart; but you will need some method of writing the blob stored in the database to the filesystem.

Comment: The objects are stored on the server itself not in the database. I have problem passing name of the object to the declaration. I need a dynamic way of doing this.

Comment: In which case, if the name of the file is stored in the database, then with the BDC connection use DataViewWebPart and in the XSL output the `new SWFObject` declaration using a combiniation of `xsl:text` and `xsl:value-of` tags.